# Line/b-spline charts with movable data points and integral/area calculation (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, charts

I'm looking for some sort of jQuery plug-in that will create charts where I can drag the data points.  B-splines and area/integral calculation features would be nice, but if that is impossible, then no biggie.

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com): looks amazing and supports b-splines, though I'm not sure it has area/integral calculation functionality.  Unfortunately, they have no demo where the data points are movable, so I'm rather worried that I'll have to end up programming this myself.  It also costs $80-360 depending on the license, and I'd prefer to avoid spending money if I can... especially if I'm not going to get movable data points.

[jQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/index.php): Movable data points, but whether or not it can be made to avoid multivalued functions (e.g. two y values for one x value -- a zigzag) is unknown to me.  Most likely does not have area/integral calculation functionality, but seeing as how it doesn't have b-splines, that would be extremely easy to add.

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/):  Looks ok, but there is no demo of movable data points.  Unless I'm missing something, Flot seems like it isn't what I'm looking for.

My question is basically this: Is there a jQuery plug-in that would do what I need without much work?  Am I missing one, or am I wrong about the functionality of some of the above plug-ins -- for example, does HighCharts have movable data points?

Answer (score 0):

You can download HighCharts and work with it for a while without having to pay for it.  If you decide that it is what you need, then you can purchase a license.  I'm doing the same thing for a report engine I am building.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library for doing the same. It is currently in a very basic shape but you can expect it to improve over time. Also it is in lean shape so you can make modifications of your own.

https://github.com/akshar100/Rapheal-Drag-Chart